# Crontab with django: ValueError not enough values to unpack

Tags: django, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm implementing crontab with my django project and am getting a error which I'm unable to figure out the cause of:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/stein/Documents/renbloc/api_web/ebdjango/manage.py", line 19,
>   in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/Users/stein/Documents/renbloc/api_web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/Users/stein/Documents/renbloc/api_web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 375, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/Users/stein/Documents/renbloc/api_web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/Users/stein/Documents/renbloc/api_web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/Users/stein/Documents/renbloc/api_web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_crontab/management/commands/crontab.py",
>   line 29, in handle
>       Crontab().run_job(options['jobhash'])   File "/Users/stein/Documents/renbloc/api_web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_crontab/crontab.py",
>   line 141, in run_job
>       module_path, function_name = job_name.rsplit('.', 1) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

I have the following in the settings.py file:

```
Cron_Dir = BASE_DIR + '/api/cron/my_cron_job'

CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', Cron_Dir)
]
```

and the function my_cron_job is just:

```
def my_cron_job():
    a = 1+1
```

I first thought crontab somehow got 2 functions registered instead of one but after removing all tasks with:

```
python manage.py crontab remove
```

and then adding the tasks again I still get the same error.

Would really appreciate some help.